# "_OBJC_CLASS_$_JobsXmlParser" Error

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, sdk

I have found this error when i build my app i import its class but still error

Comment: That's not enough information. For one, this surely isn't the whole error message. Then we need context: what are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the JobXMLParser class is not found. Are you linking it from some other framework? That being the case, check for your header search paths. And yes, the information is really not enough.

Comment: :) great. But at this point too, giving a little info about what was the flaw and how you solved it could be helpful for many "dark" who will face similar situation in future.